# how do I debug an error in module.ngfactory.ts

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have an app built with Angular 2, the [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) and ngrx, it works fine with `ng serve` and `ng build` but `ng build --prod` fails with:

`ERROR in /webapp/src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts (229,102): Property 'stateReducer' does not exist on type 'typeof "/webapp/src/app/app.module"'.`

My understanding is that `app.module.ngfactory.ts` is a file that is generated by Angular from my file `app.module.ts` and I'm a bit mystified about how to go about debugging this, other than doing a binary search to find what commit introduced the failure...

`app.module.ts` looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AuthComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    StoreModule.provideStore({stateReducer}),
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [MyService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Can anyone provide some tips for debugging this kind of error?

Comment: Try: `StoreModule.provideStore(stateReducer)` or check [AoT Don'ts](https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter#aot--donts)